# NullPointerException while comparing two strings

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, string-comparison

I think this method should work, but I keep getting nullpointer exceptions when I try to use the remove method.

I have added 8 things to the heap, and then print them off one by one by using the `remove()` method. On the second one every time I get a null pointer exception, but I have no idea why? So, I tried `System.out.println(example.remove());` in a for loop, but it would print one thing then give me a null pointer exception. My IDE says the null pointer comes from the remove, then from the percolate, then originating at the compare.

How can I fix this problem?

```
public class GenericHeap<E> {
    private int size;
    int capacity = 10;
    public E[] heap;
    Comparator mycomparator;

    public GenericHeap(Comparator c) {
        this.size = 0;
        heap = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        mycomparator = c;
    }

    public E remove() {
        E returnval = heap[1];
        heap[1] = heap[size];
        size--;
        this.pop();
        this.percolatedown(1);
        return returnval;
    }

    private void pop() {
        E[] temp = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(heap, 0, temp, 0, size);
        heap = temp;
    }

    private void percolatedown(int i) {
        while (i * 2 <= size) {
            int kid = minchild(i);
            if (mycomparator.compare(this.heap[i], this.heap[kid]) == 1) {
                E temp = this.heap[i];
                this.heap[i] = this.heap[kid];
                this.heap[kid] = temp;
            }
            i = kid;
        }
    }

    private int minchild(int i) {
        if ((i * 2) + 1 >= size) {
            return i * 2;
        } else {
            if (mycomparator.compare(heap[i * 2], heap[(i * 2) + 1]) == -1) {
                return i * 2;
            } else if (mycomparator.compare(heap[i * 2], heap[(i * 2) + 1]) >0) {
                return i * 2 + 1;
            }
        }
        return i*2;
    }
}
```

The comparator class:

```
public class StringComparator implements Comparator <String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String t, String t1) {
        if (t.length() > t1.length()) { // null pointer here
            return 1;
        } else if (t.length()<t1.length()){
            return -1;
        }

        if (t.compareTo(t1)<0) {
            return 1;
        }
        if(t1.compareTo(t1)>0) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

and I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hw10.StringComparator.compare(StringComparator.java:10)
    at hw10.StringComparator.compare(StringComparator.java:6)
    at hw10.GenericHeap.percolatedown(GenericHeap.java:82)
    at hw10.GenericHeap.remove(GenericHeap.java:53)
    at hw10.Tester.main(Tester.java:62)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: *nullpointer exceptions* on which line? please add a stack trace and point the line where the NPE occurs.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of  `mycomparator` you are passing to your constructor?

Comment: Yes, and I'm kind of new to this site, how do I point to the specific lines? What key should I use, because most things I'm putting in are messing with the format

Comment: @tokola add a comment: `// NullPointerException occurs here:`

Comment: Ok, it should be good to go

Answer (score 1):

When you try this : System.out.println(example.remove()); in a for loop you get a result only of the first example and for the second one NullPponterException, that means that your second example is null.

try this:

```
List<GenericHeap> genericHeapList = new ArrayList<GenericHeap>(...)
for(GenericHeap example : genericHeapList){
    if(example != null){
        System.out.println(example.remove());
    }
}
```